# How to reduce space between PagerTabStrip indicator elements

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am developing an application using android viewPager with tabs as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

my issue concerns the two indicators `Page 0` and `Page 1`. I want to center them on my viewpager and whenever i click on or swipe, it will display the content.

here is my XML layout:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vpPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp" />

  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its supported in `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip`.
But I can recommend you to use another library for the same effect.
I am using:

> PagerSlidingTabStrip by astuetz

It works well.
After you add the lib to your project, set `pstsShouldExpand` to true and it will fill the tabs.

Comment: Hi @motis10, thanks for answering my issue, I notice app:tabMode is unknown for the PagerTabStrip.